# Unix: How can I count all lines containing a string in all files in a directory and see the output for each file separately

Tags: unix, grep, wc

In UNIX I can do the following:

```
grep -o 'string' myFile.txt | wc -l
```

which will count the number of lines in myFile.txt containing the string.
Or I can use :

```
grep -o 'string' *.txt | wc -l
```

which will count the number of lines in all .txt extension files in my folder containing the string.
I am looking for a way to do the count for all files in the folder but to see the output separated for each file, something like:

> myFile.txt 10000
>
> myFile2.txt 20000
>
> myFile3.txt 30000

I hope I have made my self clear, if not you can see a somewhat close example in the output of :

```
wc -l *.txt
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why not simply use `grep -c` which counts matching lines? According to the [GNU grep manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html#General-Output-Control) it's even in POSIX, so should work pretty much anywhere.

Incidentally, your use of `-o` makes your commands count every occurence of the string, not every line with any occurences:

```
$ cat > testfile
hello hello
goodbye
$ grep -o hello testfile
hello
hello
```

And you're doing a regular expression search, which may differ from a string search (see the -F flag for string searching).

Answer (score 1):

Use a loop over all files, something like

```
for f in *.txt; do echo -n $f $'\t'; echo grep 'string' "$f" | wc -l; done
```

But I must admit that @Yann's `grep -c` is neater :-). The loop can be useful for more complicated things though.

Comment: Use "$f" for files like "Count my lines.txt" and remove the -o as @Yann explained.

Comment: @WalterA Oh. I didn't quite understand Yann's comment properly. Thanks! But `"$f"` wouldn't really help because the globbing (is that the term?) produces single words already. (`grep -c string *.txt`  fails in the same way.) One should use `find -print0`  with `xargs -0`, but I had the feeling that the OP was not familiar with loops (or he wouldn't have asked), so it is not meant as a production quality solution but merely as a concept.

Comment: @WalterA Hm. I take that back -- `grep -c string *.txt`  with one file `a b c.txt` works (cygwin here). How? Shouldnt it just expand to `grep -c string a b c.txt`, and none of these  3 files exist?

Comment: The expansion is done once. The shell will give the expanded *.txt as one argument. The problem starts when using in a for. After touching "a b c.txt" try `for f in *.txt; do echo $f; grep x $f; done` and 
`for f in *.txt; do echo $f; grep x "$f"; done`.

Comment: @WalterA Thanks, instructive. So the result of Pathname Expansion is a true list of strings, not a single string. I never knew.

Comment: The expansion is aware that `a b c.txt` is one word, and in a Unixy environment (like Linux or, hopefully, Cygwin) this form can be preserved as programs receive a simple array of arguments (argv). Other operating systems may use different calling conventions, such as DOS which passes a single string, leaving the program to split it into arguments. It's the expansion of `$f` which causes a second splitting into multiple words; avoid it by using `"$f"`.

Comment: @YannVernier Thanks for the clarification. I was indeed not aware of that until I read Walter's comment and had this discussion. Yes, of course, cygwin handles arguments the same way :-).